# How to use time in if else statement to change background of android app

Tags: java, android

I am using openweather api and in response i am getting date like 1648292136 after converting it to date it becomes `Sat Mar 26 16:28:44 GMT+05:30 2022`. To convert it i used:

```
Long updatedAt = response.getLong("dt");
Date ctime = new Date(updatedAt * 1000);
```

now I want if else statement like:

```
if(time between 6PM && 4AM)
{
  app background = moon;
}
else
{
  app background = sun;
}
```

Comment: Try to fetch current time and then apply this condition

Comment: Parse the date into your required format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String dateString = DateFormat.format("HH", new Date(updatedAt)).toString();
int dateHour = Integer.parseInt(dateString);
if(dateHour < 18 && dateHour > 4)
{
  app background = moon;
}
else
{
  app background = sun;
}
```

This will work completely fine for you

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @sambhav-khandelwal just needed to change some things like instead of "hh" it will be "HH" and if else statement will be something like this:

```
if((Integer.parseInt(dateString) >= 19)) 
  { 
      //Night background 
  } else if (Integer.parseInt(dateString) >= 4) 
           { 
               //Day Background 
           } else 
                { 
                   //night background 
                }
```

Comment: you are right but using simple if else was not working according to your answer it was if HH>18 && HH<4 this statement can never be true as a number cannot be greater than 18 and at the same time less than 4

Comment: Yeah that's what was needed to apply check